# Input number between 1 to 5 in Java

Tags: java

The user must enter a number between 1 and 5.
My problem is that when the user enters the value 0, the program doesn't close.

I don't understand where comes the problem?

```
int number = -1;

while(number < 1 || number > 5){
  System.out.print("Enter your number please : ");
  number= input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug. It is the best way to find out what is wrong with your code

Comment: number => 1 && number <= 5

Comment: @Jens: Yes, it's true.